# Checking if Java Platform SE is enabled on Firefox

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, applet

I want to run applet on client system but before that I want to check if java plugins are installed and enabled

There are two java plugin in Firefox.

1. Java Deployment Kit
2. Java Platform SE

I want to check enable/disable status of `Java Platform SE` plugin in Firefox.

I am able to check `Java Deployment Kit` enable/disable status using following Javascript code

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function checkJavaPlugin()
{
   if(deployJava.isPluginInstalled()==true)
   {
       alert('Java plugin installed');
   }
}
</script>
```

From what I have searched, it seems that such a thing does not exist. :O

Comment: *"There are two java plugin in Firefox."*  Huh?  The first one is JS as mentioned in [What is the Java Deployment Toolkit?](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/deployment_toolkit.xml).  But see [Java™ Rich Internet Applications Deployment Advice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) for the guide meant for developers.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem.. now, FireFox is blocking java and asking to activate the plugin while opening the applet. Is there anyway to simplify this process to open a JAVA Applet in FireFox?

Comment: I don't know.. Only good thing I know is to get rid of Java in browsers..! hahahaha...

Comment: This code can also detect Java plugin. `(function(n) {
 var p, i, o;
 if(n && (p = n.plugins)) {
  for(i=0; i<p.length; i++){
   o = p[i];

   if(o.name.indexOf("Java") !== -1)
    alert("Found");
  };
 }
})(navigator)`

Comment: But I don't have Java Platform SE installed on my PC, so I can't tell whether enuming `navigator.plugin` works for this one.